# Configure JAXB plugin for eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jaxb, xsd

I'm trying to create java classes from xsd file.
I used jaxb plugin from the link [here](https://www.assembla.com/code/lehmanRepo/subversion/nodes/Libraries/JaxB%20Parser/org.jvnet.jaxbw.eclipse_1.1.zip?rev=431). 
Now I am using eclipse-java-helios-SR2-win32 version. After added the plugin, I couldn't able to access JAXB project.
But JAXB project (Jaxb - 2.1 and 2.2) is working fine in Kepler versions. But, I need JAXB Version 2.0 specifically. That's why I am using older eclipse versions.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the following plugin will help you:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jaxb-builder/

In its description, it says it creates JAXB 2 as you want.